# Why no vertical lines in tables?

Tags: line-art, book, data-visualisation, tables, publishing

Some publisher styles ([APA](https://wmich.edu/sites/default/files/attachments/u273/2018/7%20APA%20Tables%20rev%2009_18_0.pdf), [Chicago](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/journals/know/prep-table), [SVMono Springer](https://www.cs.vu.nl/%7Ejansa/ftp/BK0/mono/instruct.pdf), …) require that tables contain no vertical lines (“unless [the lines] indicate the structure of the data” for Chicago). Why such a generic and simultaneously one-sided requirement?

Sometimes you don't have enough horizontal space to separate table columns.  Moreover, you don't have to take care about perspective because a table is not a photo or a photo-like illustration. Of course, you could hypothetically claim that vertical lines could be seen as clutter (as in [Why should lines be avoided in tables?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62847/why-should-lines-be-avoided-in-tables)), but then the requirement would apply also to horizontal lines, not only to the vertical ones.

And we're not convinced about the generality of the no-vertical-lines-in-tables rule because the examples where the line removal pays off are ad-hoc; you could easily construct little-horizontal-space examples where line removal makes columns hard to separate visually, or where table columns are grouped and groups have to be visually separated.

So why do certain publishers insist on requirements such as “The layout of your tables should not contain any vertical lines”?

Comment: No one can really answer this but publishers... and it has more to do with style guides for *that publisher* than some universal rule or law. -- Why do some people hate Miracle Whip, but others prefer it over mayonnaise?

Comment: A guess would be that it could cause readability issues. Including vertical lines could potentially make reading along the rows more difficult, interrupting the eye as it scans across the page. Horizontal lines don't interrupt the flow of the text in that way, so these aren't so problematic.

Comment: @Scott https://www.google.com/search?q=no+vertical+lines+in+tables leads to MANY publishers; this suggests some universal principle. As a ***clever*** publisher, you don't impose a requirement unless you think you need it.

Comment: @BillyKerr It's an argument, albeit a weak one because similarly, you might claim, at least hypothetically, that a horizontal line, especially if it's unique in a table and has full width, seperates too much, making the reading think that the text above the line is not connected to the text below the line.

Comment: Why do most banks use blue for their logo? No *legitimate* reason.. but by using blue they are generally "seen" as part of the financial industry. It's just a *choice* they made. Banks can, and do, use greens and reds as well. Publisher's aren't any different. Several *may* choose the same overall style aspects so that when you switch between publishers, there's an air of familiarity to the work. But it's still *all* merely style choices.

Comment: @Scott No, there is an explanation for blue, though I would not call it legitimate, I'd simply call it damn good. Blue conveys faithfulness, security and order. We associate blue with lots of positive qualities, such as sympathy, harmony, or friendship. This is a general, statistical statement, I admit, and exceptions might exist, of course. Still, your love for blue most likely comes from you lying as a kid in a buggy, seeing a blue sky, and feeling happy. Anyhow, I heard you, thank you, and let us speak about vertical lines here.

Comment: Really? Explain Wells Fargo then, Bank of America, Citizens Bank. Or the 3 or 4 smaller banks around here using greens and yellows for branding. As I commented, it's a style *choice* nothing more. To me blue conveys emergency services, help needed, hospitals, police, or..if lighter....  laziness (as in lazy days), a relaxed attitude, beach combing, etc. But you can bet if I'm creating branding for a financial institution, it's going to have at least one iteration that's blue - to "go with the herd".

Comment: @Scott Let's take an example. The red color (of, say, Wells Fargo or Santander) conveys passion, energy, warmth, and self-confidence. Red is for the brave. You've made your point that the colors differ. True, and they differ because of the different perceived marketing purposes. This would very well speak for the intentional omission or purposeful introduction of vertical lines on per-table basis, perhaps on a per-book basis, depending on the best look of a particular table or of the tables of a book. But by no means this particular purpose could extend to ALL books of a publisher.

Comment: It's just a choice -- red can convey blood, death, hellfire, Satan, hate, anger. Sure, search the web and you get the standard "Purple means royal. Blue means secure. Red means love. Green means growth." They are only common interpretations *because* they are common interpretations. Its a self-propelling cycle. So.. vertical lines are merely a common interpretation used by publishers. But there's no rule stating you must or must not have vertical lines for tabular data in general.

Comment: In my experience a publishers style guide is just that.. a guide for *all* work. So yes, it would be a universally used style in all work from a publisher. Which is why specifications would dictation no vertical lines in tables - to remain consistent with that publishers style guideline. (Note, I have a tendency to write as if I'm adamant about something and can come across unduly aggressive. I honestly don't mean to convey that sentiment at all. - please read realizing I'm smiling `:)`)

Comment: @Scott Red is a color of signal, essentially due to blood being red, while some other culture-specific red items might exist (think of China). Other interpretations are based on the statistics gathered by the marketologists. It's damn hard to imagine they make this stuff up out of thin air (orelse you'd probably agree that they lose their job quickly). As for the publishers, similarly, they cannot make their guidelines out of thin air. As for the rule, the publishers do not say it's a suggestion.

Comment: @Scott I see “In APA style, tables have no vertical lines.”, “Only horizontal lines are allowed; no vertical lines […]”, and “The layout of your tables should not contain any vertical lines”. These are clearly dictations. You might claim that the publishers are not adamant about these, but that would be a whole different story on the usage and interpretation of the written guidelines.

Comment: I never claimed the publishers weren't going to be adamant about the lines. I *claimed* that there's no basis for the *choice* other than *stylistic preferences*. There's no technical limitations which present themselves when reproducing a table with or without vertical lines. Imagine, I simply don't like the flavor of cilantro. I'm not allergic to it and it certainly won't do me any harm if I eat it. I simply *prefer* to not to experience that flavor. So, I'm *adamant* about having no cilantro in my food. If you serve me something with cilantro, I'll send it back. That's all publishers do.

Comment: @GeekestGeek i wouldnt read too much symbolism into color. It is common to see designers claim colors do this and that but the scientific evidence is weak. If the data was clearcut other choices than one choice would be clearly wrong. Since its not its a syle choice. But anyway the tabular without lines data may have a reasoning. If you read E.R.Tufte you will notice he will give you one: Less clutter, although he gives others too. Still a sort of motivated stylistic choice though. Publishers choose this because they have read Tuftes books. And indeed it makes for a quite refined look & feel.

Comment: @Scott: *No one can really answer this but publishers* – Obviously the question doesn’t ask us to read the mind of whoever created these rules, but for design principles that could possibly have lead to them. If questions on understanding design principles are not for this site, I don’t know what is. In this particular case, there may be no principle, but even that would be an answer to this question and is nothing the asker could trivially see beforehand. If there is no principle underlying any design choice, this implies that all graphic designers are frauds.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i dont have my references with me. But basically the reasoning is as follows:

- Cramming too much data in a small space makes it harder to absorb
- A human can separate things by using whitespace just as well as by a line.
- Adding the line makes things harder to absorb because it adds more clutter.

So essentially you want this line because you want to put too much data in and you dont have enough whitespace. There are many ways you can arrange more space like rounding numbers, aligning differently, transposing the table etc.

In the end your supposed to summarize data. Then share raw data somehow else. But obviously this is only a oppinion for presenting data for understandability and from design appeal. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks! This kind of reasoning doesn't differentiate between horizontal and vertical lines, as opposed to the publishers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are some important differences between horizontal and vertical lines, which all eventually originate from the pertinent writing systems being horizontal and not vertical.

- It is standard to arrange tables such that the same type of information is arranged in columns, not rows. This in turn is because in a horizontal writing system, it is better to align similar information on top of each other instead of next to each other. As a result, the majority of academic tables have distinct index rows (a.k.a. header rows), but no index columns. By *distinct,* I mean that they contain a totally different type of information, e.g., “weight” as opposed to “5 kg”. It makes sense to separate these index rows visually by a horizontal line. (This line also serves as a visual indicator that the agglomeration of characters you are viewing is a table.)
- Since the height of rows is usually much smaller than the width of columns in a horizontal writing system, readers are much more prone to jump across rows than columns. Further, the aforementioned predominance of columns makes it often easy to notice if you are in the wrong column. Thus, while horizontal lines may be called for for eye guidance occasionally, vertical lines hardly ever are.
- In many academic contexts, it is common to have footnotes below a table. To separate these, it makes sense to add a horizontal line at the very bottom. In a horizontal writing system, we usually wouldn’t put something like footnotes on the side of a table.

In my experience, the vast majority of academic tables need exactly one line, namely to separate the index row (header) from the body. A horizontal line at the very bottom can be added as a stylistic choice or to separate footnotes or similar. Everything else is unnecessary and visual clutter. There are rare occasions where more lines, sometimes even vertical ones, are called for, but those make up for far less than one percent.

Also, in my experience, most academics tasked with formatting a table will use every line they possibly can, resulting in badly readable tables. Thus, I can fully understand that publishers radically restrict line use in their rules as a default. The same publishers may even accept vertical lines, if the authors can argue that their particular table requires them. So, this rule may not be cast in stone, but presenting it as if it were is the lesser evil.

> you could easily construct little-horizontal-space examples where line removal makes columns hard to separate visually, or where table columns are grouped and groups have to be visually separated.

I would guess that even in the majority of these special cases, you end up with a better table if you first force the authors to work without vertical lines and think of better ways to present the data, e.g., by reducing the need for horizontal space or visually separating groups otherwise.